# React unable to render object property

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm attempting to render the values of props object,  When I `console.log` stats object, chrome dev tools console shows the following object.

```
Object
_id : "vFgY3YBrLj3Pd7zNA"
active: 652668928
available: 595034112
createdAt: Fri Jan 13 2017 03:56:04 GMT+0400 (GST)
free: 595034112
inactive: 563294208
ownerId: "6Kv93sJdY62iGiCwg"
percent : 86.1
```

However when I attempt to access `.stats` property I get `undefined`

```
   console.log(this.props.stats._id);

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Any idea on what I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Can you paste your component code, where is stats coming from and how is it being passed

Answer (score 1):

Check this `jsfiddle`, how to pass props values from parent component and use in child component : https://jsfiddle.net/r7ym0x4r/

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that this behavior happens because the object is not fully instantiated

In my case the query to fetch object data was slow, here is an example for fetching last record

```
Stats.findOne({}, {sort: {DateTime: -1, limit: 1}});
```

And when I changed it to something like, it worked fine.

```
Stats.find({}).fetch();
```